# Stream rtsp video using axvlcplugin to a file

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, vlc, rtsp

I am using VLC plugin to run an rtsp stream. The stream works good. But I want to store these videos to a file destination. I use this code but does not work.

```
    axVLCPlugin21.playlist.add("rtsp://192.168.10.222:554/h264", null, ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,acodec=flac,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:file{dst=C:\\123.ogg,no-overwrite} :sout-keep");
    axVLCPlugin21.playlist.play();
```

This code only plays the rtsp stream but does not store. However, the same options can be used to stream directly on the VLC player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VLC does not support recording of streams via plugin. Check this [Link](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=114850)

I got a work around for it. I record the stream by calling the VLC directly. However, the player is hidden. I use this code:

```
Process.Start("C://Program Files//Videolan//VLC//VLC.exe","\"rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:554/h264\" --qt-start-minimized --sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,acodec=flac,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:file{dst=C:\\123.ogg,no-overwrite}");
```

Comment: is it efficient to use such a way to record stream from ip tv (many channels will be recorded according to a schedule)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this Option for Storing Videos and displaying videos simultaneously

**original commad to play in vlc**

```
%vlc path% vlc.exe -vvv rtsp://192.168.10.22:554/h264 :sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,acodec=flac,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=file{dst=C:\\\\123.mp4},dst=display}:sout-keep
```

if this works try to use

```
 :sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,acodec=flac,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:duplicate{dst=file{dst=C:\\\\123.mp4},dst=display}:sout-keep
```

":sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,acodec=flac,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:file{dst=C:\123.ogg,no-overwrite} :sout-keep
also try to work in VLC gui by using streaming option+displaylocally+dst=file

Refrence:[HowTo Receive and Save a Stream](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aStreaming_HowTo/Receive_and_Save_a_Stream/)

Comment: Nope. Still doesn't work. Are you using rtsp streams?

Comment: Use `sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo}` in transcode module just for test

Comment: Yes.. I tried almost all the options available. Looks like the vlc does not support it.